# Stacked Bar Graph Plot using Pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame as follows -

```
    DeviceType  All Transactions    Non Fraud Transactions  Fraud Transactions
  0 desktop        85165            79611                    5554
  1 mobile         55645            49988                    5657
```

The `All Transactions` is a sum of `Non Fraud Transactions` and `Fraud Transactions`

How do I plot a Stacked Bar Graph so that I can eliminate `All Transactions` column?

Comment: Use `df.set_index('DeviceType').drop('All Transactions', 1).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure want `stacked=True`, but you may not need `set_index`:

```
df.plot.bar(x='DeviceType', 
            y=['Non Fraud Transactions', 'Fraud Transactions'],
            stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Note: `plot.bar(...)` is equivalent to `plot(kind='bar',...)`.